# PHP API Authentication

Tags: php, api, authentication

I have a mobile application which is using an API I have set up with PHP. I am wanting to secure the API so that only people with the API key can interact with the API. I have read conflicting information on what is secure and what isn't, so I am hoping someone can tell me if what I am doing is considered secure.

My intention is to distribute a randomly generated API Key which will be passed with each request to the API using HTTP POST or GET:

> apidomain.com/api/data.php?apikey=vueh43u348uhfu&customdata=1

When the server receives the request it will check the API key is valid and display the results appropriately.

```
    <?php

    if($_GET[‘apikey’] == “vueh43u348uhfu”){

       echo “Data Returned.”;

    }else{

       echo “forbidden”;
    }

    ?>
```

I am assuming that because the domain is secured with an SSL certificate that passing the API key in in the URL is a safe thing to do? or have I got this wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't send the API key in a `GET` request, instead utilize the `Authentication` in the header.

Comment: To elaborate on that a bit, the reason it's a bad idea to use a query-string parameter for this is that it'll be saved in plain-text in a lot of different places - server logs, browser history, etc. An HTTP header is a much more secure (and conventional) way to manage this.

Comment: brilliant thank you!